# most efficient way to write data into a file

Tags: ruby, io

I want to write 2TB data into one file, in the future it might be a petabyte.

The data is composed of all `'1'`. For example, 2TB data consisting of `"1111111111111......11111"` (each byte is represented by '1').

Following is my way:

```
File.open("data",File::RDWR||File::CREAT) do |file|
  2*1024*1024*1024*1024.times do
  file.write('1')
  end
end
```

That means, `File.write` is called 2TB times. From the point of Ruby, is there a better way to implement it?

Comment: i guess it would be more faster to create the string before writing it instead of calling write each time. strings in ruby are mutuable, so you don't need to create a new string on permutations.

Comment: Do you want binary 1 bits (`0b1111`) or ASCII "1" (`0x31`) on the disk?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a few problems:

1. `File::RDWR||File::CREAT` always evaluates to `File::RDWR`.  You mean `File::RDWR|File::CREAT` (`|` rather than `||`).
2. `2*1024*1024*1024*1024.times do` runs the loop 1024 times then multiplies the result of the loop by the stuff on the left.  You mean `(2*1024*1024*1024*1024).times do`.

Regarding your question, I get *significant* speedup by writing 1024 bytes at a time:

```
File.open("data",File::RDWR|File::CREAT) do |file|
  buf = "1" * 1024
  (2*1024*1024*1024).times do
    file.write(buf)
  end
end
```

You might experiment and find a better buffer size than 1024.

Comment: You may also write to shift the bits instead of multipling which would be a little faster `(2<<10<10<<10)` == `(2<<30)` for `(2*1024*1024*1024)`

Comment: @ted Sure, but it's a calculation that only happens once, so that wouldn't make a measurable difference, just a theoretical one measured in nanoseconds. We could really save time by just writing `2147483648` directly ;)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know which OS you are using but the fastest approach would be to us a system copy to concatenate files to one big file, you can script that.
An example.
If you start with a string like "1" and echo it to a file

```
echo "1" > file1
```

you can concatenate this file with itself a number of time to a new file, in windows you have to use the parameter /b for binary copy to do that.

```
copy /b file1+file1 file2
```

gives you a file2 of 12 bytes (including the CR)

```
copy file2+file2 file1
```

gives you 24 bytes
etc

I will let the math (and the fun of Rubying this) to you but you will reach your size quick enough and probably faster than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

A related answer, if you want to write binary zeros with any size, just do this using the dd command (Linux/Mac):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=output_file bs=128K count=8000
```

bs is the block size (number of bytes to read/write at a time.
count is the number of blocks.
The above line writes 1 Gegabyte of zeros in output_file in just 10 seconds on my machine:

```
1048576000 bytes (1.0 GB) copied, 10.275 s, 102 MB/s
```

Could be inspiring to someone!

Answer (score -2):

The data is all ones?  Then there is no need to write the ones, just write the number of ones.

```
file.write( 2*1024*1024*1024*1024 )
```

Simple, yes?

Comment: I'm giving the questioner the benefit of the doubt and assuming there's actually a reason they want to do what they're asking.

Comment: Well, questioner should have said 'random ones and zeros'...  But, in nearly all cases runtime encoding will be a better solution anyway.