# Why does `File.write` slow down sometimes?

Tags: ruby, io

This is my code:

```
start = Time.now
File.write('/tmp/a.txt', 'Hello, world!')
puts "Saved in #{Time.now - start}"
```

In some cases, I see this in the log:

```
Saved in 0.001
Saved in 0.002
Saved in 0.245
Saved in 0.002
```

Why is there occasionally such a spike? What could that be? I'm not using `flock` anywhere. My suspicion is that some library has overridden the method `File.write()` and added some locking/synchronization there. Is it possible?

Update: It seems that `Dir.new()`, which regularly gets access to the directory, blocks access to it.

Comment: it's not always accurate to use Time.now to measure such stuff. Could you try to change `Time.now` to `Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC)`? More info is here https://blog.dnsimple.com/2018/03/elapsed-time-with-ruby-the-right-way/

Comment: @VasiliyErmolovich I just did, nothing changed

Comment: @egor256 Which devise you are saving file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872906/most-efficient-way-to-write-data-into-a-file

Comment: I'm always getting about 0.000255 sec

Comment: Are you writing to an SSD or to a spinning disk? Is there any other process using the storage device concurrently? I am getting 0.0002-0.0003 seconds constantly on a Mac with SSD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `Dir.new()` in another place of the app completely locks the entire directory and doesn't allow `File.write()` to work fast. This is the test to reproduce the problem (using [threads](https://github.com/yegor256/threads) gem):

```
require 'tmpdir'
require 'threads'
Dir.mktmpdir do |dir|
  file = File.join(dir, 'hey.txt')
  Thread.start do
    loop do
      Dir.new(dir)
    end
  end
  Threads.new(100).assert do
    start = Time.now
    File.open(file, 'w+') do |f|
      f.write('test')
    end
    puts("Saved in #{Time.now - start}")
    sleep 1
  end
end
```

This one will work slow. However, if you replace `Dir.new` with this, everything moves fast again:

```
`ls #{dir}`.split(' ')
```

Ruby bug? I don't know.

BTW, the same is true for `Dir.glob()` - it's also very slow.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I would be very surprise those spoke of time does not come from Ruby but from your underlying operating system (Linux I guess).

I wrote a similar script than yours in Python, I could watch same difference than you.

I watch it's systemcall using:

`sudo strace -T -e trace=open,close,write -p <my_process_pid>`

And at least for the `open` syscall, I could also watch some call taking 100 time long than others.